# Fastapi bcypt hash not able to login

Tags: hash, fastapi

```
  from passlib.context import CryptContext

pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=['bcrypt'],deprecated="auto")


class Hash():

    def get_password_hash(password: str):
        return pwd_context.hash(password)
      
    def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
        return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)
```

I called the hash function from the authentication  class
router = APIRouter(
tags=['authentication']
)

```
@router.post('/login')
def login(user_credentials: userlogin, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    
    user_email = db.query(User).filter(user_credentials.email == User.email).first()
    if not user_email:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f' wrong email')
    
    if not Hash.verify_password(plain_password=user_credentials.password,hashed_password=User.password):
        print("here")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    #create taken
    return{"taken":"example taken"}
```

same how it is not able to authenticate the user even though he is in the database. the second if in the authentication class is returning not found, even though the user is present in DB.

```
  if not Hash.verify_password(plain_password=user_credentials.password,hashed_password=User.password):
        print("here")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: In your call to `verify_password`, you're using `User.password`, i.e. the class, not the instance. Change this to `user_email.password`.